# Windowsphone put method to spring rest

Tags: c#, spring, rest, windows-phone-8, put

I am new to Windows Phone. I have a vacation object which I want to update in my database.
I use Spring as REST API, and I have a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/vacation", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes ="application/json")
public void updateVacation(@RequestBody Vacation vacation){
    new VacationDao().update(vacation);
}
```

In my Windows Phone application, I have following put method:

```
public async void PushSubscription(Subscription subscription)
    {
        try
        {

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

            // Write the request Asynchronously 
            using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(httpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream,
                httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null))
            {
                //create some json string
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subscription);

                // convert json to byte array
                byte[] jsonAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

                // Write the bytes to the stream
                await stream.WriteAsync(jsonAsBytes, 0, jsonAsBytes.Length);
                MessageBox.Show("Ik geraak hier");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I don't have any exception and I'm sure I'm passing the code in my WP client, but I can't pass the code on the server...

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it not solve setting the ContentType to `application/json` instead of `text/plain`?

You can also try using `HttpClient` which serves me better than create WebRequest every time, you also write less code.

```
public async void PushSubscription(Subscription subscription)
{
    try
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subscription);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            await client.PutAsync(apiUrl, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Ik geraak hier");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```